# as3 readind mysql RSS feed delayed

Tags: php, android, actionscript-3, flash, rss

I am making an android application with adobe flash pro that reads  an RSS updated by (MYSQL database) and php.

The application is perfectly works.

When a new item is added to the database it is simultaneously displayed in my rss feed when I open it with my computer (or mobile) browser.

The problem is that it sometimes takes up to 5 minutes to be updated in my application (some times less than 5 seconds)

How to solve this (delay problem)

samples of the Rss feed

```
                  <rss version="1.0">
                 <channel>
                 <title>RssName</title>
                 <description>rssDescription</description>
                 <image>
                 <lnk1>rssImageLink</lnk1>
                 </image>
                   <item>
                            <title>
                            Title Number 1
                            </title>
                            <time>14:49:57</time>
                   </item>

                   <item>
                            <title>
                            Title Number 2
                            </title>
                            <time>14:48:31</time>
                   </item>

                   <item>
                              <title>
                            Title Number 3
                            </title>
                            <time>14:46:04</time>
                   </item>

                   <item>
                            <title>
                            Title Number 4
                            </title>
                            <time>14:41:47</time>
                   </item>

                 </channel>
                 </rss>
```

The as3 code is (urlLoader) and  XmlList

I used (rss version="2.0")  but it didn't work !

this is my as3 Code

```
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;
        import flash.events.Event;

        //////////// Defines Xml Lists for downloaded 
        var titleArr:XMLList ;
        var pTimeArr:XMLList ;


    ////////////////////////////////////////// Laod List RSS//////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var xmlData:XML = new XML();
    var url:String = "http://www.Domain.com/news/rss.php" ;

    xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadXML);
    xmlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loaderIOErrorHandler); 

    function LoadXML(e:Event):void 
    { 

    xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);

        ////// Add Rss Items to XmlLists
        titleArr = xmlData.channel.item.title ;
        pTimeArr = xmlData.channel.item.time ;

    displayNews()
    }  




    //////// Load RSS Xml Content
    function refreshing(e:MouseEvent):void {
        xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest(url));
    }

    ///// Button to refresh content
    refresh_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,refreshing)



    //////////////////////////////// Display Mews /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function displayNews()
    {

        trace(titleArr,pTimeArr) ;

    }


    ////////// Handling Errors 
    function loaderIOErrorHandler(e:Event){
            trace("Error"); 
    }
```

Comment: We need more info about your connection algorithm in as3. When the applications ask for updates? Give us a sample of code

Comment: From what you describe your application only sends out a RSS request every 5 minutes. Increase the interval frequency for faster updates. If you don't think it's that, try to do what SharpEdge suggested.

Comment: In my application I press a button (refresh_btn) any time to refresh content.

Comment: if I change the (rss.php) name the complete rss is loaded at the first time then If I add items they wont appear in the xmlList (Besides it is loaded much faster in the second time as if there is cache data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot the solution is to prevent the (rss.php) from making cache